# K-theory of a discrete groupoid crossed product

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, groupoids

Does there exist a method to compute the K-theory
$$K(A \rtimes G)$$
for a discrete, countable groupoid $G$ and $G$-$C^*$-algebra $A$? In good cases, say $G$ is ameanable.

Say, via Baum--Connes and a Chern-character? But which Chern character?

(This question has partial overlapp with [K-theory of topological groupoids](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108438/k-theory-of-topological-groupoids?rq=1))